# Could you find a counter example to this bfs algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, shortest-path, dijkstra

I tried to review Dijkstra's algorithm. In my first attempt, I wrote a BFS algorithm for finding shortest paths. I know this algorithm shouldn't work, because this bfs algorithm has complexity O(V+E), which is better than Dijkstra algorithm in complexity. But I couldn't find any counter example to the BFS algorithm. (I also implemented the correct Dijkstra algorithm as a comparison.)

```
from typing import List, Dict
from heapq import heappush, heappop
from collections import deque

def bfsVisit(graph: List[Dict[int, float]], source: int)->List[float]:
    """
    :param graph: adjacency list representation of graphj
    :param source: source node
    :return: distance from source to all other nodes
    """    
    n = len(graph)
    distance = [float('inf')] * n
    distance[source] = 0
    toExplore = deque([source]) 
    explored = [False] * n
    while toExplore:
        u = toExplore.popleft()
        if explored[u]:
            continue
        explored[u] = True
        for v, weight in graph[u].items():
            tempDist = distance[u] + weight
            if tempDist < distance[v]:
                distance[v] = tempDist
                toExplore.append(v)
    return distance

def dijkstra(graph: List[Dict[int, float]], source: int)->List[float]:
    """
    :param graph: adjacency list representation of graph
    :param source: source node
    :return: distance from source to all other nodes
    """
    n = len(graph)
    distance = [float('inf')] * n
    distance[source] = 0
    toExplore = [(0, source)]
    while toExplore:
        dist, u = heappop(toExplore)
        if dist > distance[u]:
            continue
        for v, weight in graph[u].items():
            tempDist = dist + weight
            if tempDist < distance[v]:
                distance[v] = tempDist
                heappush(toExplore, (tempDist, v))
    return distance
```

Could you find a counter example to the bfsVisit?
I have tried multiple graphs, but both bfsVisit and Dijkstra produce the output I expected.
Both my Dijkstra and bfsVisit passed my tests below.

```
from pytest import fixture, mark
from pytest_lazyfixture import lazy_fixture
from dijkstra import dijkstra, bfsVisit

@fixture
def graph1():
    graph = [None for _ in range(6)]
    graph[0] = {1: 1, 3: 4, 4: 2}
    graph[1] = {2: 3, 3: 1}
    graph[2] = {}
    graph[3] = {2: 1, 5: 2}
    graph[4] = {3: 2, 5: 3}
    graph[5] = {}
    return graph

@fixture
def graph2():
    graph = [None for _ in range(6)]
    graph[0] = {1: 1, 3: 4, 4: 2}
    graph[1] = {2: 3, 3: 1}
    graph[2] = {5:1}
    graph[3] = {2: 1}
    graph[4] = {3: 2, 5: 3}
    graph[5] = {}
    return graph


@fixture
def graph3():
    graph = [None for _ in range(3)]
    graph[0] = {1: 1, 2: 3}
    graph[1] = {2: 3}
    graph[2] = {}
    return graph

@mark.parametrize('graph, expected', 
                  [(lazy_fixture('graph1'), [0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4]), 
                   (lazy_fixture('graph2'), [0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4]),
                   (lazy_fixture('graph3'), [0, 1, 3])])
class TestShotestPath:
    def test_dijkstra(self, graph, expected):
        assert dijkstra(graph, 0) == expected

    
    def test_bfsVisit(self, graph, expected):
        assert bfsVisit(graph, 0) == expected
```

Comment: this article has an example in C#, maybe it gives you some inspiration. https://itbackyard.com/how-to-make-shortest-path-in-grid-using-bfs-in-c/

Comment: It looks to me like the problem isn't correctness. The problem is that your BFS can have much, much worse than O(V+E) runtime, due to repeatedly reexploring visited nodes every time it finds a shorter path than it previously knew about. (This reexploration also makes it not really a BFS.)

Comment: `graph[0]={1:1,3:9} graph[1]={2:1} graph[2]={3:1} graph[3]={4:1} graph[4]={}`

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks I got the problem of the BFS algorithm. Distance to an explored node can be updated. However since BFS won't re-explore an explored node, the adjacent node distance won't be properly updated and hence a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

BFS and Dijkstra should return different results for a graph like this:

```
S--10---T
 \     /
  1   1
   \ /
    A
```

If they don't, then you did one of them wrong.